# C# ListView Hook Pre SizeChanged Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, hook

I have a ListView in tile mode. I have created a custom method to fire when the SizeChanged event is fired. Is there anyway to override this so the method fires before the SizeChanged event is fired?

I tried looking for a SizeChanging event but there isnt one. How can I do this?

Comment: what is setting this change off? Client window size; code, etc.?

Comment: Only the form's ResizeBegin event is a candidate here.  Relevant only if the list view is docked or anchored.  Anything else requires a time machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In order to add some logic before the `SizeChanged` event is fired, you'll need to subclass the existing `ListView` control.** Create a new class in your project and paste this code into it:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Fire my custom method before the ListView's size is changed
        MyCustomMethod();

        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }

    private void MyCustomMethod()
    {
        //Insert your custom logic here
        //...
    }    

}
```

Then build your project, and use this `CustomListView` control (or whatever you decide to name it) instead of the standard `ListView`.

Alternatively, if you want to decouple the custom logic from the control itself, you can have your custom listview raise an event instead. Then, you can handle this new event (we'll call it `SizeChanging` for consistency) wherever you need in your code. For example, modifying the above example:

```
public class CustomListView : ListView
{

    public event EventHandler SizeChanging;

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        //Raise the SizeChanging event before the ListView's size is changed
        if (SizeChanging != null) {
            SizeChanging(this, e);
        }

        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: nitpicky: `Control` derives from `System.ComponentModel.Component` and all control (and Form) events are managed by `Component.Events` (`System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList`). It is advisable to use this mechanism rather than adding event pointers to your Control instance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx

Comment: @Tergiver: Interesting, I don't think I've ever seen that anywhere. Out of curiosity, since the documentation that you link to doesn't say that, is there somewhere in particular that's suggested, perhaps with an example?

Comment: If you're asking for a better than Tergiver reference that recommends using that pattern, I don't have one. I would encourage you to exercise logic. A class with 20 events has 20 pointers, even if there are no subscribers to any of those events. Using Component.Events reduces your class' footprint by eliminating the pointers. The link I gave has an example in the community content section. Control.Events is already exposed (protected), so you don't have to declare it. I dislike the use of string keys in the example, preferring `static readonly object KeyIdentifier = new Object()` instead.

Comment: I added an example as an answer to show your code modified to use Component.Events.

Comment: @Tergiver: I see. I think you might be talking about the same thing covered in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx. But the way I understand that (and your last comment) is that it gives you a finer level of control over the add/remove accessors for an event, which is useful when you're exposing a lot of events, but probably not necessary in ≈95% of cases.

Comment: @Tergiver: I also find this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt1k2w4e.aspx, which seems to indicate the primary reason to implement this is memory management in the case that a control is exposing a lot of different events which are not likely to be used. Writing custom events this way allows an application to use memory only for the events that it handles. In the context of the question that was asked, this is hardly a concern; he's seeking to add this event so that it can be used directly.

Comment: @Cody: Yes, the benefit is reduced memory footprint. Since Controls already expose this mechanism, why would you *not* use it? I agree that this is a simple example and that it's rather nitpicky in this case. My aim, as always, is to expand other people's knowledge base.